# Batch find and replace for Sublime Text 2

Tags: text, replace, automation, sublimetext2

I have to paste code from a latex source repeatedly, so I have to do a lot of find and replace operations every time ('"a' => 'ä', '"o' => 'ö', ...).

Is there a way to store those search & replace rules, so I can execute all of them with one keypress for example?

Comment: Maybe this script could help you: https://gist.github.com/phillipkoebbe/1519543

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you check [RegReplace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace)? It is a simple find and replace sequencer plugin for Sublime Text 2. It can be installed through Package Installer.

In the end you will have to create some files that will look as follow:

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+t"],
    "command": "reg_replace",
    "args": {"replacements": ["change_a_accent", "change_o_accent"]}
}
```

Comment: That's even better than what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo I got lost in your code (where replacements come?) until I went to github repo...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to encode/decode LaTex accents, I have created a spetial plugin for this : https://github.com/kpym/SublimeLaTeXAccents .